# SP 2016 on -premises error: Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server

Tags: permissions, 2016, people-picker, sharepoint-server

while sharing permission and in all sorts of people picker i'm getting this error **"Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server"** 
[image]
on clicking **Shared with** i'm getting error "**unexpected response data from server**"
[image]

i tried the following,

- resetting IIS,
- restarted the server
- different user names
- memory space is sufficinet

Please help me in fixing this error

Comment: Can you check if rest api is working?

Comment: Does this issue happen for all the web applications on the farm?

Comment: Did you check this issue ?https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/260958/sharepoint-2016-people-picker-error-sorry-we-re-having-trouble-reaching-the-se

Comment: yes it is happening in all the web applications in the SharePoint farm

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Install and activate HTTP Activation as mentioned in below link.

[Install and activate HTTP Activation](https://windowsreport.com/trouble-reaching-server-sharepoint/#2)

Also check that all the Application Pools are up and running.

if the issue still persist then kindly provide the ULS Logs.

Comment: thanks dhruvil29. ....HTTP is already activated , and with the ULS logs i found there is a issue with my user profile services, then checking furthur, i found that the port number which i used is restricted one, i've mentioned it in my answer,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who helped me.. i tried all your methods, unfortunately i couldn't fix my issue.
Finally...
i found the issue it is the **Port number of the web application** which is a restricted one and it doesn't allow the user profile service to fetch the names form the active directory, and after changing the correct port number the issue has been fixed.

**Thanks again everyone..**

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why you might be getting this issue . Please check all of these

- Try IIS reset once from all front end servers.
- Check Alternate Access Mappings settings for the web application.
- Try deactivating "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"
  Feature from site collection features
- Make sure the domain account you are using for a SharePoint service
  account has the necessary permissions to read domain accounts, If you
  have one-way trust domain - Set the app password (stsadm -o
  setapppassword -password "Password") and follow the KB to add people
  picker domain https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2874332
- Check if Anonymous Authentication is enabled for your web site in
  IIS.
- Try updating "Query timeout" value from 25 to 60! (under:
  15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\clientpeoplepicker.js >>
  SPClientPeoplePicker.UserQueryMaxTimeout)
- Try extending the web application to new port!

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I just solved this issue today by following this [post](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/07/sharepoint-2013-people-picker-sorry-were-having-trouble-reaching-the-server.html).
In my case, I enabled Anonymous Authentication in IIS as the other items were already configured in the server.