# People picker not working says "Sorry unable to reach server"

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker, 2019, port

I have SharePoint 2019 environment and configured the multiple domain for people picker. but when i searching for the user in people picker i got "Sorry unable to reach server". My environment is firewall enabled. I need to know what are the ports and which server the ports should be open either WFE or App Server.

Can anyone help me on this. Thank in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the Port number of the web application and try to perform iisreset.

A similar post:
[SP 2016 on -premises error: Sorry, we're having trouble reaching the server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269046/sp-2016-on-premises-error-sorry-were-having-trouble-reaching-the-server)

Another blog for reference:
[We’re having trouble reaching the server SharePoint error [FULL FIX]](https://windowsreport.com/trouble-reaching-server-sharepoint/)

Comment: Elsie Lu_MSFT - Thanks for your answer, HTTP Activation is already installed also my web application port is not restricted and it's running on port 80. As I said, configured multiple domains (Domain 1 and Domain 2). SharePoint server resides on Domain 1 and its fetching for Domain 1 users correctly. Only this problem raise if I add Domain 2 to people picker

Answer (score 0):

After opening the port in Domain 2 its works.